# Individual political belief test (Social and Economic Conservatism/Liberal)

Tags: political-psychology

I'm looking for a framework (question types) to estimate the political belief of participants. The survey will then be given to people from different parts of the world, but mostly occidental.

[The 12 Items Social and Economic Conservatism Scale (SECS)](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0082131) (Everett, 2013) is pretty good but it only measures conservatism. In my knowledge it also was not used in large-scale survey such as the [European Social Survey](http://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/), [European Value Study](http://www.europeanvaluesstudy.eu) or [The World value survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/wvs.jsp) making the result not comparable to the global population.

There is the [Political Compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_compass), but the test is very long and not documented.

My target is to be able to place peoples on a two-dimensional scale, with very few questions:

[image]

**References**

Everett, J. A. (2013). The 12 items social and economic conservatism scale (SECS). *PloS one*, 8(12), e82131. doi: [10.1371/journal.pone.0082131](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0082131)